# Sed or AWK: Add line after each ocurrance of pattern between a range of line numbers

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I need to add a line of text after each occurence of a pattern. I need this:

```
pattern1
pattern2
```

To look like this

```
pattern1
pattern2
new line data here
```

The new line data will always come after pattern2. pattern2 will always be the same and I have well over 100 occurences of patter2. And I only want to do this when I seen pattern 2 between lines 226 and 2858. I would like to do an in-place modification and do all this without wiping out anything else in the file. (already did that once while testing, don't want to do it again)

UPDATE - I need to be more precise as my patterns contain special characters. So I'm actually changing this:

```
pattern1
pattern2 { text; };
```

to this

```
pattern1
pattern2 { text; };
new data { text; text; text; };
```

So matching on pattern 2 that contains special characters and adding the new data line with the special characters. Should have disclosed that before. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: So, how does `pattern` come into play?

Comment: Does it *have* to be `sed` or `awk`, or would using a different tool be acceptable?

Comment: Does not have to be sed or awk just was the first thing to come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with vim!

```
vim file.txt -c "226,2858g/pattern2/normal onew line data here" -c "wq"
```

You can also do this interactively by doing this:

```
vim file.txt
:226,2858g/pattern2/normal onew line data here
:wq
```

Which is the way *I* would prefer to do it, but I would understand if you prefer the first, being unfamiliar with vim.

The way both of these work is by calling vim's `:global` command:

```
                        *:g* *:global* *E147* *E148*
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
            Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
            lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

In this case, the range is lines 226-2858, the pattern is "pattern2", and the ex command is

```
normal onew line data here
```

What this does is it calls "normal" which means "Enter the following keys as if I had typed them". Typing the 'o' key (o)pens a new line below the current one, and enters insert mode. Then, while in insert mode, the text "new line data here" is inserted into the file.

The next command `-c "wq"` is just (w)rite and (q)uit.

If your "pattern" uses regex, you should probably read through [this wonderful page](http://vimregex.com/) to help you troubleshoot if the pattern is matching correctly.

Comment: explain "normal onew" please

Comment: @user53029 Sure! See my edit. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Much better thanks. I think I can work with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "226,2858s/^\(pattern2.*\)/\1\nnew line data here/g" -i data.txt
```

Comment: This did not work. It may have been due to special characters. See my updated question.